# Matplotlib: white margins and hidden axis when saving figure

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've been trying to save a plot I made with matplotlib, but I have been having some issues: not only I get the usual white margin problem (to which I found some solutions online), but it seems that my axes and labels are disappearing when I save the image, though they appear just fine when I ask Python to `show()` the result. Here are a MWE, a print screen of the result I get with `show()`) (which is the one I desire) and the result I get when I save the figure to a .png (I believe the white margins are indeed solid, for they were not transparent when I tested a .svg file generated in the same way).

```
from pylab import *
import numpy as np

L=5.05
dx=0.01

def func(x,v):
    return np.cos(2*np.pi*v*x)*np.exp(-np.pi*x**2)

def main():
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1,figsize = (12,8))
    #fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0)

    ax.set_facecolor((0.118, 0.118, 0.118))
    fig.patch.set_facecolor((0.118, 0.118, 0.118))

    ax.grid(linewidth='0.25')

    ax.spines['bottom'].set_color('white')
    ax.spines['top'].set_color('white') 
    ax.spines['right'].set_color('white')
    ax.spines['left'].set_color('white')
    ax.tick_params(axis='x', colors='white')
    ax.tick_params(axis='y', colors='white')

    ax.annotate(r'$\nu=2$', xy=(5.1, -0.9), color='white')

    (c2,) = ax.plot(np.arange(-L, L, dx), func(np.arange(-L, L, dx),2), color=(0.949,0.506,0.396), linewidth = 1.8)

    ax.set_xlabel(r"Tempo $t$", color='white')
    show()
    return
```

[Printscreen of the desired result (obtained with `show()`)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZuPg.png)

[Result obtained when saving figure through GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrdCq.png)

Any ideas about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you save the figure the background set by `fig.patch.set_facecolor((0.118, 0.118, 0.118))` is drawn in the area around the figure. The labels are still there, they are just invisible as they are white on white.

Compare your output to the same figure without the background colours set below.

[image: Your figure][image: Figure on white background]

If you pass the `facecolor` parameter to `.savefig` it will draw this colour behind the entire image, and your labels will be visible as intended.

```
fig.savefig('testoutput.png', facecolor=(0.118, 0.118, 0.118))
```

[image: Savefig with facecolor set]